# Javascript - How to get more voices for text to speech?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

I made this little script where you can enter some message and it reads it out.

I solved it by using FireFox SpeechSynthesis API.

How can I get more voices and support for more languages?

> Note: There is a "bug" in SO. If I edit my question and edit the script and test it from there, then 4 voices are
> loading. If I run the code snippet normally, then no voices are
> loading, but the default voice.

```js
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
 // Speech Synthesis supported
} else {
  // Speech Synthesis Not Supported
  alert("Sorry, your browser doesn't support text to speech!");
}

const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
populateVoiceList();

if (typeof speechSynthesis !== 'undefined' && speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged !== undefined) {
  speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = populateVoiceList;
}

var selectedLang = $("#voiceSelect").find("option").attr("data-lang");
var selectedVoice = $("#voiceSelect").find("option").attr("data-pos");

$("#voiceSelect").change(function() {
   selectedLang = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-lang");
   selectedVoice = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-pos");
});

$("#start").click(function() {
    var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

    msg.text = $("#message").val();
    msg.lang = selectedLang;
    msg.voice = voices[selectedVoice];
 
    console.log(msg);

    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
});

// Hide Dropdown if there is only one voice
if ($("#voiceSelect option").length == 0) {
    $("#voiceSelect").hide();
}

function populateVoiceList()
{
  if (typeof speechSynthesis === 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = `${voices[i].name} (${voices[i].lang})`;

    if (voices[i].default) {
      option.textContent += ' — DEFAULT';
    }

    option.setAttribute('data-lang', voices[i].lang);
    option.setAttribute('data-name', voices[i].name);
    option.setAttribute('data-voice-uri', voices[i].voiceURI);
    option.setAttribute('data-pos', i);

    document.getElementById("voiceSelect").appendChild(option);
  }
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="voiceSelect"></select>
<div class="flex-container">
    <textarea id="message" value="test"></textarea>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xyftpqo/)

Comment: to answer your bounty question why there are different voices on each device:
https://talkrapp.com/speechSynthesis.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get more voices and support for more languages?

Currently there isn't a browser vendor that supports loading custom/more voices. It doesn't appear to be part of the nascent specification yet either, as there is an [open issue asking how to add more voices](https://github.com/WICG/speech-api/issues/100).

The list of voices is dependent upon the user agent/device because that is how it is [specified](https://wicg.github.io/speech-api/#dom-speechsynthesis-getvoices). User agents are using either a native speech engine provided by the device OS or a network based speech engine, each of which work with a set of supported voices. Here is a [comment from a chromium issue about not being able to support boundary events](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521666#c7) because of the missing capabilities in the native/network based speech engines, as an example of the platform the Web Speech API is dependent upon.

If you want to see what voices are available for various devices/browsers you can go to https://morganney.github.io/tts-react/?path=/story/tts-react--hook and click the "load" button to get an HTML `<select>` of the `SpeechSynthesisVoice`'s supported.

You can also run the snippet below to see what voices are available:

```js
let voices = []
const btn = document.getElementById('load')
const options = document.getElementById('voices')
const hasSynth = 'speechSynthesis' in window

if (hasSynth) {
  voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
  
  speechSynthesis.addEventListener('voiceschanged', () => {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
  })
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const initOpt = document.createElement('option')

  if (!voices.length && hasSynth) {
    voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices()
  }
 
  initOpt.append(document.createTextNode('-- select voice --'))
  options.append(initOpt)

  voices.forEach(voice => {
    const option = document.createElement('option')
 
    option.value = voice.name
    option.append(document.createTextNode(`${voice.lang} - ${voice.name}`))
    options.append(option)
  })
  
  options.style.display = 'inline'
})

options.addEventListener('change', (evt) => {
  if (hasSynth) {
    const utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance()

    utterance.text = 'Testing the selected voice.'
    utterance.voice = voices.find(voice => voice.name === evt.target.value)
    
    speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)
  }
})
```

```css
#voices {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="load">click to load voices</button>
<select id="voices">
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly altered your code and have a working version here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/j36nbhy1/

First we set synth variable and also a let to initialise voices as an empty array which we can push to later

```
const synth = window.speechSynthesis;
let voices = [];
```

Then we have to pass `voices = synth.getVoices();` inside our `populateVoiceList` function as the call to it works asynchronously.

Then I changed the `for loop`, for a `forEach` function like so:

```
voices.forEach((item, index) => {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = `${item.name} (${item.lang})`;
    option.setAttribute('data-lang', item.lang);
    option.setAttribute('data-name', item.name);
    option.setAttribute('data-voice-uri', item.voiceURI);
    option.setAttribute('data-pos', index);
    document.getElementById("voiceSelect").appendChild(option);
});
```

I think the rest is pretty much the same, but let me know if you get issues. I did have to make a couple of edits in order to test.

Comment: Ok thx, but I see no difference in the end product? There are also only 4 voices loading.

Comment: There are 90 in the array. I am now console logging them in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/j36nbhy1/.  Also see this screenshot. Is your code cached? https://i.imgur.com/emIP48I.png

Comment: Unless your array is being overwritten after the call?

Comment: Do you also see 90 if you are using my jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/8xyftpqo/ | I just tried it again with my work laptop and there I get over 20 voices. It seems like it is different for every device. Why?

Comment: I just forked your fiddle. As I mentioned you must move `const voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();` inside your populateVoiceList function otherwise it will not work.  https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/476my0k1/
I did not that trying on Chrome, Safari and Firefiox returns a different number of voices. I don't know why, it must be linked to the way the api is implemented, I am trying to look into it.

Comment: There is no difference if I use my script or yours, it loads the exact same amount of voices.